# Test Deep Link Notification using Facebook not working in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, deep-linking

I'm trying to test a deep link notif using **Facebook's App Ad Helper tool**. However, I'm getting the following error message: **Deep link notification could not be sent for the chosen platform.**

[image: deep link error]

Anyone experienced this and how did you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to lack of App ID entered in application settings. I am unsure if it is the only possible problem causing this message, but after adding App ID from my app on appstore notification with deeplink was successfully sent to device

Comment: Hi Mac Slayer, welcome to Stackoverflow. Thanks for you contribution.

Answer (score 0):

In https://developers.facebook.com/apps/712694549805037/settings/basic/, Go to iOS Platform and make sure that `iPhone Store ID` has a valid value. For me it was not working till the time this value was empty.

You can get this id without even shipping your app to the app store.
But you need a developer account for the same.